# Adding a hash in the back URL when validating with custom request

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm validating a form in Laravel, defined like this:

```
class ContactFormRequest extends Request
{ ... }
```

And in my controller I have:

```
public function contact_form(ContactFormRequest $request)
```

and everything is just fine. The request validates and returns to `Request::back();` with the errors.

How can I add a hash to the back URL, like `/contact_form#hash`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found it.
In the constructor of the custom request add:

```
class ContactFormRequest extends Request
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->redirect = URL::previous().'#custom_hash';
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old thread but, if any one search, I believe that the right way to do it is :

```php
/**
 * Get the URL to redirect to on a validation error.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function getRedirectUrl()
{
    return parent::getRedirectUrl() . '#custom_hash';
}
```