# Laravel Form Request Validation - Append hashtag at the end of route URL

Tags: php, laravel

I am using a form request class to validate form and I am trying to use a custom URL.

```
    protected $redirectRoute ='account.settings';
```

That is what I have right now. But I want to append a hashtag at the end of it. I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
protected $redirectRoute ='account.settings' . '#general';
```

It simply says:

> Route [account.settings#general] not defined.

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a hash in the back URL when validating with custom request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29255804/adding-a-hash-in-the-back-url-when-validating-with-custom-request)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `route()` function:

```
protected $redirectRoute = route('account.settings') . '#general';
```

Comment: You cannot use function there. Expression is not allowed as field default value.

Comment: Ah you are right.  Sorry I don't have any other ideas